# Event in extended sap.m.Table not triggering

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to extend the sap.m.Table control following [this article](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/d5b756bf4e9a4d67961fa21e1ba12c9e.html)
Everything is working fine. The control is rendering and displaying all content correctly.

But the event will not be fired.
What am I missing? Do I have to hook on to a different event? I thought I can just override the onItemPress event of the sap.m.Table control and enhance it the way I want, since I don't need the original functionality.

Any pointers to a solution would be appreciated.

Before trying to extend the control I already tried to hook on to the onItemPress event by using `.addEventDelegat()`, which did not work either.

**My extended Control:**

```
sap.m.Table.extend("CollapsableGroupTable",{
    metadata:{
       events:{
          "groupCollapse" : {}
       }
    },

    onItemPress : function(evt) {
        this.fireGroupCollapse();
    },
    renderer : {}
});
```

**My instance of the control:**

```
var oTable = new CollapsableGroupTable({
            columns : [
                <some columns>
            ],
            items : {
                path: "<somePath>",
                sorter : <someSorter>,
                factory : <someFactoryFunction>
            },
            groupCollapse : function(){console.log("group collapse event fired");},
        });
```

**Edit:** Just for clarification the override of the event not working is idependent of the item type. I tried with active as well as with inactive.

Answer (score 1):

`onItemPress` is an external Event.

You should check which function in `sap.m.Table` is triggering that event and override that function to also trigger your event.

Comment: So I can't override external events?

Answer (score 0):

By default the type property of ListItem will be inactive, so that the itemPress event will be ignored. Change you ListItem type to 'Active'.

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#event:itemPress

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListType.html

Comment: Thx for answering. I am aware of this behaviour, that is why I am trying to override the onItemPress which is the event where the control checks for the type and depending on that then fires the itemPress event.